# Attempting to return a single value when duplicates are returning based on earlier open date:

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Say I have 300 Locational providers and some of these work at multiple locations. Each location has a billing address but I only want to return the Billing address for the location that the provider opened first (That Open date) This solution is what I asked for, but I guess what I should have asked for is how can I get it to return the earliest open for each Provider

Comment: Please provide query in text format instead of images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Window functions are your friends.  Try something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT DISTINCT
    L.Open_DT
    , bil.*
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY L.Open_DT) AS Rnk
FROM tbl_Location L
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [MOAD].[dbo].[qry_Location_Address_Billing] bil
        ON L.Location_ID = bil.LocationID
WHERE L.Group_NPI = '*******'
) AS R
WHERE Rnk = 1
```

Comment: Now, what if I wanted do this where there were many rows, not for like a single example:

Say I have 300 Locational providers and some of these work at multiple locations.  Each location has a billing address but I only want to return the Billing address for the location that the provider opened first (That Open date) 

This solution is what I asked for, but I guess what I should have asked for is how can I get it to return the earliest open for each Provider

Comment: Add a Partition By clause to the OVER function to include any columns on which you want to group by.   E.G. - Row_Number() over (partition by group_npi order by L.open_dt)

Comment: Beautiful.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use row_number and select 1 as below

```
Select * from 
    (
    Select L.Open_dt, bill.*, 
        RowN = Row_number() over(partition by Address_type, Street1, City, State order by L.Open_DT desc) from tbl_Location L
    left join ...
    ) a
    where a.RowN = 1
```

Comment: Close, but if you partition by every field and they are not all the same, every row will come back with a value of 1.  Drop the partition clause of the over function and only use the order by clause.